# Calculate the highest salary for each department

Tags: sql

I have to create a report which displays the highest salaries in each department. 
I must have the following columns, department_id, department_name, last_name and MAX(salary). And it cannot contain any duplicates.

I have managed to get a query result with all the columns however due to the last_name column I have a query result as the following.

```
90, Executive, De Haan, 17000

90, Executive, Kochhar, 17000

80, Sales, Tucker, 10000

80, Sales, Bernstein, 9500

80, Sales, Hall, 9000
```

Obviously, the highest in the Executive department is 17000, and 10000 in Sales. I need to display only 1 salary amount for each department. Any ideas on how I achieve this?

Below is what I typed into SQL to get this result.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT department_id, department_name, last_name, MAX(salary)

FROM    employees

NATURAL JOIN departments

GROUP BY department_id, department_name, last_name

ORDER BY MAX(salary) DESC;
```

Comment: what columns are in the employees table?

Comment: Department_id, last_name and salary

Comment: You've got conflicting requirements. On one hand you want to include last name, which gives multiple records when more than one person has the highest salary, and on the other hand you only want one record per department. If you really want only one record, and you don't care which person you return then you'll need to look at something like partitioning on department and salary,. and just select the first record.

Comment: Okay thanks, I in no way thought it was going to be possible very easily. This is part of an assignment my teacher gave....

Comment: Currently your question is not clear. Can you kindly share complete sample data (not just the answer set) and your desired output?

Comment: Forget about the NATURAL JOIN construction. Stick to explicit JOIN conditions (to save you and others pain when table definitions change.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? MySQL or SQL Server or Oracle ...? Or do you want an answer for Standard SQL instead?

Comment: And please answer what you want to do in case of ties. What do you want to show in the last_name result column when there is another record `80, Sales, Miller, 10000`? (Easiest solution would be `NULL`. In some DBMS it would also be easy to display a concatenated string `'Miller, Tucker'`.)

Answer (score 0):

So you need to find the max salary per department id then join back to the employee table to pull the last name. Something like this:

```
SELECT sub.department_id, sub.department_name, emp.last_name, sub.max_sal
FROM
(SELECT e.department_id, d.department_name, MAX(e.salary) AS max_sal
 FROM employees e
 INNER JOIN departments d
 ON e.department_id = d.department_id
 GROUP BY e.department_id, d.department_name) sub
INNER JOIN employees emp
ON sub.department_id = emp.department_id
AND sub.max_sal = emp.salary
```

Note that this solution would show multiple people if they have the same salary and it's the highest for their department.